# Mass look-up Organization ID when uploading CSVs into Data Loader?

Tags: data-loader

I am trying to mass upload Donations to Data Loader.   Among other values, in my CSV document, I need to have an Organization ID.  Is there a way to quickly get the ID from the Organization Name, or through any other route?

Comment: If you mean the Salesforce.com Organization Id, you can grab it from Setup > Company Profile > Company Information.  If you mean linking to an Organization (Account) Record, you can use an external id field if one is available.

Comment: They're (apparently) using NFP edition, so an Organization is just an Account (Donation is an Opportunity...). This is fairly trivial in Microsoft Excel through a VLOOKUP formula. Create a sheet with the organization name and ID (left to right, sorted by name ascending), then use a VLOOKUP in Excel, something like =VLOOKUP(A2,Org!$A$1:$B$2000,2,false), where A2 is the organization name, the cell reference is the sheet containing the sorted data, and 2 and false is the column to use (ID) and exact lookup mode (false means exact lookup).

Comment: -TechTrekker- I know I can get it from there, but that's tedious to do for each organization.  Is there an interface that will automatically grab the ID, given the name?

@Sfdcfox, You're correct, I'm using the NFP edition.  I'm not sure you understand.  I don't have the Organization IDs in my excel spreadsheet.  I was given a list of Opportunities containing only the Organization name.  I don't want to have to look up the ID for each one, so I was asking for a way to automatically extract that data GIVEN the name, perhaps through an external app.

Comment: Create a report on Organizations, include the Organization ID and Organization Name. Export that report to Excel, and then VLOOKUP. It's the free solution to the problem. If you want to pay money, then there's solutions like Data Junction (by Pervasive), and Cast Iron (and others, too; I'm not specifically endorsing either app). These apps can transform data automatically via mapping, and save countless hours of data conversion.

Comment: Ah, I gotcha.  You clever dog.